# protoc: command not found (Linux)

Tags: protocol-buffers

I am trying to use Protobuf on Linux box. I downloaded the pre-compiled from [github](https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.5.0).

When I try to compile my .proto file or just check the protobuf version, it says

> protoc: command not found.

I tried the same steps on Windows machine using pre-compiled protobuf version and it works fine there.

Comment: this sounds like an install issue rather than anything else; if you don't want to install it: does `./protoc` work?

Comment: With ./protoc same issue. Command not found.

Comment: and you're in the folder with the protoc binary at the time? if you `ls`, does `protoc` appear?

Comment: yes, it appears.

Comment: Most likely it uses different runtime linker that your system don't have, or just wrong architecture. You can check with `readelf -l protoc | grep interpreter`.

Answer (score 49):

Install protoc for Linux and Mac

**Linux**

```
PROTOC_ZIP=protoc-3.15.8-linux-x86_64.zip
curl -OL https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v3.15.8/$PROTOC_ZIP
sudo unzip -o $PROTOC_ZIP -d /usr/local bin/protoc
sudo unzip -o $PROTOC_ZIP -d /usr/local include/*
rm -f $PROTOC_ZIP
```

**Mac OS X**

```
brew install protobuf
```

Alternately, if you don't have Homebrew.

```
PROTOC_ZIP=protoc-3.15.8-osx-x86_64.zip
curl -OL https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v3.15.8/$PROTOC_ZIP
sudo unzip -o $PROTOC_ZIP -d /usr/local bin/protoc
sudo unzip -o $PROTOC_ZIP -d /usr/local 'include/*'
rm -f $PROTOC_ZIP
```

source: http://google.github.io/proto-lens/installing-protoc.html

Answer (score 13):

For Linux Ubuntu 20, only install with **snap**

```
snap install protobuf --classic
```

or via **apt**, with:

```
sudo apt install protobuf-compiler
```

Comment: or `apk add protoc` on Alpine

Answer (score 6):

I know this question is specifically asked for Linux and I could n't find any question as it relates to solving this error on Windows.

This might help people who encounter the same error on windows.

**Step 1:** Download the windows distribution (protoc-3.5.0-win32.zip) from the link [protobuf](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.5.0) and unzip locally to a folder

**Step 2 :** Add the folder path to the path in the system environment variables.

[image]

[image]

**Step 3:** close the command prompt, restart the command prompt and try the command protoc

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can try it:

Install grpc and protobuf

`brew install grpc protobuf`

Answer (score 4):

I might be late to the party but I also had "command not found" when trying to run protoc. It turned out it was just missing the execute permission. A quick `chmod +x protoc` fixed this for me.